# How to see access statistics for just one file with AWStats?

Tags: awstats, filtering

My hosting provider uses AWStats (and Webalizer). I can browse the stats, and see the overview and various filtering functions. I also can see the so called exit and entry pages.

However, I can not see how to have a statistic of the access of a single file (an image for example), regardless of whether it was called on entry or exit or whether it is in the top 10 or not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AWStats on the left side below Viewed click on Full List which will tell you how many times a single file was accessed

Comment: @ Anagio: Ok, that solved the problem, but only partially. I do host 3 domains on that server, and each one points to a certain subdirectory on the server. It seems that the name of the subdirectory is omitted in the log. Probably because the request uses the "host" header field? So, I have records of those 3 domains but they are mixed up. Is there a way to separate them?

Comment: @Marcel I'm not sure about that I would begin using Google Analytics which will let you create filters for your reports. This was not part of the original question to be fair if you feel I answered it feel free to mark it, I don't know of any way to filter reports in AWStats please look into GA. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Google Analytics. I actually looked into it but I feel uncomfortable with their License Agreement. They require me to have a Privacy Statement meeting their like, which I don't like. I will not use Google Analytics for the moment.

Comment: @Marcel Google "Open Web Analytics" you host it yourself and it provides excellent analytics for your site.

Comment: @Marcel: This will depend on your setup, but in cPanel, if your 3 domains are set up as add-on domains pointing to different subdomains then AwStats should report on these separately as there will be 3 different access logs. However, if these domains are _parked_ on your hosting account and you are internally rewriting to the respective subdirectories then there is 1 access log for AwStats to report on.

Comment: @w3d Thanks for clarifying this. In my case, it will be most likely that my hosting provider uses what you call "parked", because the single available log actually contains data from all 3 domains.

Comment: @Anagio Thanks for mentioning Open Web Analytics. I actually found this comparison page: http://web-analytics-software.findthebest.com/compare/1-9/Google-Analytics-vs-Open-Web-Analytics